# How to find missing files with sequential names?

Tags: files, filesystems, filenames

I have thousands of files named 1.txt 2.txt and so on. Some of those files are missing. Which would be the easiest way to find out which files are missing?

Comment: Are those files all in the same directory? And how far will the seqence go? Is the naming convention always the same 1.txt for the first one 105.txt for the 105th one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ub=1000 # Replace this with the largest existing file's number.
seq "$ub" | while read -r i; do
    [[ -f "$i.txt" ]] || echo "$i.txt is missing"
done
```

You can easily find the proper value for `ub` by doing `ls | sort -n` or similar. This relies on the files being in the format output by `seq`, notably here without leading zeroes.

Comment: Thanks! I created a function for this on my .bashrc. You just saved my day :)

Answer (score 5):

```
$ ls
1.txt  3.txt
$ seq 1 10 | xargs -I {} ls {}.txt >/dev/null
ls: cannot access 2.txt: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 4.txt: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 5.txt: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 6.txt: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 7.txt: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 8.txt: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 9.txt: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 10.txt: No such file or directory
$
```

Comment: No need for `seq` or `xargs`: `ls {1..10}.txt > /dev/null`

Comment: @DennisWilliamson Thats worthy of an answer and probably would be the best one :)

Comment: @heemayl except that with "thousands of files" there's a good chance you'll blow the argument count and/or argument size limit on your system, hence the use of `xargs`.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson: short, clear, simple, should be the best answer! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is the function I will be using

```
missing () {
  #ub gets the largest sequential number
  ub=$(ls | sort -n | tail -n 1 | xargs basename -s .txt)
  seq "$ub" | while read -r i; do
    [[ -f "$i.jpg" ]] || echo "$i.txt is missing"
  done
}
```

Comment: I think that the normal etiquette is that your accepting @TomHunt's [answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/236165/138566) already says that it is, to your mind, the best answer; and that you should not re-post that answer as your own (at the very least, not without attribution).

Answer (score 0):

Another (`bash`):

```
comm -23 <(printf '%d.txt\n' {1..1000} | sort) <(ls *.txt |sort)
```